# Problems with xmlHttpRequest + cookies + redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, redirect, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to login to a web service using xmlHttpRequest.

The web service in question seems to authenticate using cookies. After analyzing communication with IE browser, I concluded that the sequence is basically the following:

(1) server sends a form requesting username and password.

(2) client sends a POST request containing username and password typed.

(3) server sends a redirect message (HTTP 302) to the same URL with a "Set-Cookie" header containing the session ID

(4) client re-sends the same URL containing the cookie received from the server in redirect message.

(5) server receives session ID and concludes authentication.

I tried to emulate the same sequence using xmlHttpRequest in JavaScript. However, I found a problem.

It seems that xmlHttpRequest does not redirects cookies. I other words, (4) is not happening and authentication is not completed.

To make the problem worse, xmlHttpRequest does not seem to detect redirect events (it this was possible, I could at least set Cookie header before re-sending request). The onreadystatechange() function is called only after all re-direction process is completed.

So, I don't have any solution in mind to resolve this problem and complete authentication.

Also, as it is related a "public" web service, I am not able to change anything in the server side.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't use xmlHttpRequest to query a url of a server different to the server you are connected to. ¿Could you do it?

In explanation if the page with the javascript code is in yourdomain.com you can't use xmlHttpRequest to call a web service in example.com.

Comment: Actually the javaScript code is supposed to run in my own desktop (like opening an HTML file with a javaScript code that contains the xmlHttpRequest call to *example.com)". Yes, this usually works.

Comment: I see. What happends if you set the cookie before sending the post?
I mean, if you do a request for the form (step 0), before doing the POST, you can get the cookie there and then use it in the POST.

Comment: Yes, I already tried it, but it did not help much. I got the cookie received in (1) and re-sent it in (2). Actually, it seems that the cookie with session ID is sent only in the redirect message.

Comment: Another strange behavior is that, in xmlHttpRequest, the client  message in (4) contains the same form query passed in (2). With IE, the message in (4) contains no query...

Comment: That's because without the Session ID the server doesn't recognize you and sends you to the login form.

Comment: Can you post the urls here? Login form and redirect location?
If not, are them on the same server? Do they look like belonging to the same application on the server?

Comment: Sorry, I could not post the whole code. Anyway, I am trying url: "www.ted.com/users/signin" and query="users%5Busername%5D=" + id + "&users%5Bpassword%5D=" + pw + "&users%5Breferrer%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ted.com" + "&signin.x=19" + "&signin.y=14";

Answer (score 0):

With the previous comments I understood better the situation.

Steps (4) and (5) are only to redirect you to the main page, the real autentication ends in (3), once you get the cookies (using getheaders for example) you are logged in.
Then for every new  request you do with the correct cookies the website will see you as the logged in user.

Are you trying to automate a query to the site? Or just automate the login process?

Comment: I am trying to get information about the user that was just logged in.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know a way to get the cookie the server sent in (3). As I said, xmlHttpRequest seems to handle redirection transparently, and the event (3) is not even signalled. The callback (onreadystatechange) is called only after the whole redirection process is complete, and the cookie with the session ID is not in the final (HTTP 200) packet. How do I get that cookie?

Comment: After logging in, the resulting page contains a user ID. So, I am supposed to use this user ID to get some information about the user (url = "/profiles/favorites/id/" + userID). It looks like without the "session ID" cookie the server considers that I am not logged in.

Comment: Sorry, this is beyond my knowledge. It would be nice if IE just sets the cookie for the .ted.com domain, so the next request is done with the cookie, but apparently this isn't the behavior.

Comment: I understand. For me, it seems to be a bug in xmlHttpRequest implementation. It is strange that it will behave differently from a regular browser. Also, if it isn't a bug, there should a way around this situation.